# select all from both tables with a common column - same column name

Tags: php, mysql

table `banners`

```
| id | src       | roll |w  |...|
-------------------------
| 1  | blue.jpg  | 7    |120|...|
| 2  | white.jpg | 5    |250|...|
| 3  | green.jpg |      |140|...|
```

table `brolls`

```
| id | src        |...|
-------------------
| 4  | jones.jpg  |...|
| 5  | abba.jpg   |...|
| 7  | italia.jpg |...|
```

I need to select `all` from `both` tables

tables have different number of columns

not all rows from `banners` have a `roll` value

`banners.roll` is in fact `brolls.id`

```
while ($row = $st->fetch()){
    $items .=
    "<img src = '" . $row['banners.src'] . "'
    data-id = " . $row['banners.id'] . "
    data-roll = '" . $row['brolls.src'] . "'
    data-w = " . $row['banners.w'] . "
    alt='img'>\n\n";
}
```

So final result should be:

```
<img src = 'blue.jpg' data-id=1 data-roll='italia.jpg' data-w=120 alt='img'>
```

I need `all` images from `banners` listed this way.

Any help?

Comment: just create a `JOIN` statement, using the `brolls` and `banners`

Comment: Use aliases to distinguish between the two src columns

Comment: @Ghost, excuse me, I edited my post, not all rows from `banners` have `roll` value so in that case final result gives only two images, but I need all images from banners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify what type of database you have. I guess you are using mysql. You could be clearer on saying what you want. I guess you are looking for the SQL queries and the PHP code to sort the results the way you want.

Here is a suggestion.

The SQL must be:

```
$sql_a = 'SELECT id, src, roll, w FROM banners';
$sql_b = 'SELECT id, src FROM brolls';
```

You should get all of them in 2 different queries, and form 2 different arrays, one for each: $array_banners and $array_brolls; with the next structure:

$array_banners['id value'] = array('src' => 'src value', 'roll' => 'roll value', 'w' => 'w value')

$array_brolls['id value'] = 'src value';

Then you will do the image html coding:

```
foreach( $array_banners as $k => $v)
{
"<img src = '" . $v['src'] . "'
    data-id = " . $k . "
    data-roll = '" . $array_brolls[$v['roll']]['src'] . "'
    data-w = " . $v['w'] . "
    alt='img'>\n\n"
};
```

And ready.

Comment: regarding your starting note - see post tags, pls

Comment: @puerto I noticed that you updated the question. In the case of the banners that do not have a roll, it will be impossible to link them with a broll because none is specified. With my solution the 'data-roll' field would be automatically left blank in those cases, so if that is what you want this must work. You may also just assign a random one.